# How to keep in queue only one (latest) message from each publisher?

Tags: rabbitmq

I wonder how to tall a channel or queue or RMQ server to keep only one, latest message from each publisher? Is there in RMQ any way to get this done with out RMQ server modification -> recompilation?

Comment: have you seen the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585598/rabbitmq-messaging-initializing-consumer.  I presume you have entertained this as you are asking for a way to do it without recompiling / moding the server.  You would probably need a work around to replicate what the last value cache exchange does. Why can't you just use the last value cache though?

Comment: have you seen the answer to this question? - no, thank you for suggestion. It probably can solve my problem. But I heped if such thing can be done via configuring server\channel\queue with out havily modifiing RMQ. Via say so default client tools.