# Configure RabbitMQ to replace an old pending message with a new one

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is is possible to configure a RabbitMQ exchange or a queue in such a way that at most one message with a given routing key is pending at any time? If new message arrives, the old one would be dropped and the new one enqueued.

If such option is not available, what would be the best way to implement this at the application level? I.e. when application receives a message how can it check if there any more pending messages?

Comment: I have a feeling that you might want something like last value cache. but I am not sure.  Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do

Comment: @robthewolf I use rabbit mq to communicate between a server and a client. The server sends messages to tell the client in what state the client should be. The client can disconnect in which case the messages are enqueued and wait for the client to reconnect. When client reconnects it really is interested in the last message sent by the server, because the last message represent the state in which the server wants the client to be at this moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install Last Value Cache and enable it.  Your exchange will be type "x-lvc", which inherits from the direct exchange type.

each time you connect to MQ, create a queue and bind to this exchange.  It will deliver the most recent message to the queue. It is perfect for making sure you get only the most uptodate message.  All other messages sent to this exchange are discarded unless there is a queue connected. So once connected you will continue to receive updates.

here are installation instructions:
https://github.com/simonmacmullen/rabbitmq-lvc-plugin

here is a similar question:
[RabbitMQ messaging - initializing consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585598/rabbitmq-messaging-initializing-consumer)