# RabbitMQ mark message as Dead Letter

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

I did a lot of research but I could not find any answer for this. Is there a way to mark a message that is sitting in a Q as a dead letter?

Imagine a context where I have multiple consumers (X, Y, Z) all 3 are up and consuming messages. At some point, Y decides to stop the application and take a break, my exchange will still put messages in his Q for him to process when he comes back. (an example would be the odds changing for a football match) Is there a way to mark some of the messages in that Q as dead letter so when the application is started is not processing all the messages but only the valid ones?

Example in the time the Y consumer was stopped I send 5 messages (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5). Now with the consumer still down I want to send a new message A2 so the Q will become now (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A2) is there a way to mark the first message that was send as A2 dead letter so instead of consuming 6 messages when he comes back to consume just 5 of them (A1, A3, A4, A5, A2)

This would be something similar to RemoveAtIndex from a list where index = message having A2 name

Comment: @LutzHorn I am not able to use TTL as I can't say beforehand for how much time a message is valid. It may be 5 minutes, 10 or even one day.

Comment: Related to the problem you are looking to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451401/configure-rabbitmq-to-replace-an-old-pending-message-with-a-new-one